# Display FileName with fileUpload on Edit if file exists in a folder and filename in database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

On Edit, how to assign filename (stored in SQL database as a string) to fileupload control.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult editLeaveRequest(int id)
{
    var model = hc.leaveRequests.Find(id);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.documentUrl))
    {
        model.documentUpload.FileName = model.fName;
    } 
    return View(model);
}
```

I've saved file in a folder and its `filename(fName)` in SQL database as string. What I'm trying to do is, check if `filename(fName)` exists in the database, if so, assign it to `fileUpload`'s fileName and pass this model to ViewPage.

What I want is, display filename with the fileupload control as its status to inform user that there is a file already attached to this record and its filename is equal to `filename(fName)`. But above code is giving following error:

> Property or Indexer 'HttpPostedFileBased.FileName' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Can someone please suggest how to accomplish it?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You cannot assign a value to a file input for security reasons. Just add additional properties in you view model to indicate if a file has been uploaded, and its file name (and if so display the filename)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok. I want to display the filename as the only thing with fileUpload control and erase its default status i.e., `no file chosen` if a filename exists in the database.

Comment: If you have already uploaded the file, the don't include the file input. Just include the filename

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's right. But this is On-Edit scenario. Suppose user wants to edit the piece of document he added with the Create Action. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your last comment. Do you mean you want to allow the user to upload another file and replace the current one?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Correct.

Comment: Then (say) include the file input in a hidden element and add a button "Replace File" that displays the file input so the user can select a new one

Comment: @StephenMuecke True. That is one solution. Let's see what others say - otherwise I will implement what you suggested.  Maybe its not possible but what I wanted was, display fileupload control with the fileName next to it as fileUpload shows the fileName when we browse a file.  Thank you always.

Comment: Unless you create you own 'control' (e.g. a button that triggers a hidden file input, and an associated label), then that's simply not possible.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should live with the fact that every time you reload your page, file upload input will be empty. What you need to do is:

- Somehow show that the file exists, but in a separate block (e.g. `<div>MyFile.png</div>`)
- Add file delete functionality as needed or do your `model.documentUpload` check to see if new file was posted and if it was, replace existing file with the new one.
- Validate your form submit on the server-side to allow only one file per your entity.

[image]

Comment: @RehanKhan exactly

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another control to show currently FileName, 
Only use HttpPostedFileBase at post time to upload a new file, maybe hide this control on client side and add button EDIT to show this control